# Enabling Remote Desktop across different domain

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Have a system with Win8 within Domain A and remote has been enabled in that. Users from Domain A are able to login reomtely using admin credentials. how ever using the same credentials users from Domain B Domain C & Domain D are not able to login. Is there any setting that needs to be done so that users from other 3 domains are able to access the system either using the system admin account or using their login (added in remote desktop users account in the remote machine)

Any suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

1. Remote Desktop needs to be enabled (which it is if you are connecting to other computers from the same domain)
2. Check your router setting for port forwarding. For my Linksys router, it was under "Application & Games -> Port Range Forwarding". I had to forward `3389` to the client system trying to connect to the remote machine.
3. Finally, I had to put the port at the end of the IP. For example `192.168.1.110:3389`.

You can search your registry for the Remote Desktop port number. The default is `3389`. Open `regedit` and search for `RDP-Tcp`. Then look for `PortNumber`. You should see something like `0x00000d3d(3389)`.

Comment: It's 3389 (stupid thing wouldn't let me change only 2 characters in a post.  Otherwise - thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Achieved it by adding port# in front of the hostname while connecting RDP. Port# available in
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber> Should be able to remote from any domain with in network. Hope this helps anyone facing issues